# how to get value from rating system and save to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, angularjs

hi i got `jquery` code for rating bar from http://plnkr.co/edit/kFKejRU0G2wmkD7GlNdH?p=preview, i want to get the value from the jquery when `hovering leave` event occurs, and process in server to save to mysql database.

Here is my jquery code

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);     
var RatingDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {    
    $scope.myRate = 0;    
     $scope.submit = function() {             
         console.log($scope.percent) ; //null         }

     $scope.rate = 1;
     $scope.max = 5;
     $scope.isReadonly = false;
     $scope.percent = 20;

      $scope.hoveringOver = function(value,object) {
        console.log('hoveringOver', value);
        $scope.overStar = value;
        $scope.percent = (100 * $scope.overStar) / $scope.max;
      };

       $scope.hoveringLeave = function(rate) {             
           console.log('hoveringLeave',  $scope.rate);            
       $scope.percent = (100 * $scope.rate) / $scope.max;
      };
    };
```

want to get  percent value from `hoveringLeave` and to save it from here:

```
function callIt()   
{
    var rate=document.getElementById("rate");       
    alert();        
}
```

is there any way to get this? PLease help here.

Comment: Passing value from jQuery to javascript??? That makes me bug... Basically, jQuery is javascript

Comment: "passing from jquery to javascript" you're being redundant, what you want is to `post` data using `ajax` so your `php` script will process it

Comment: hi i have edited my question, i am new to here in jquery so having misunderstanding with these words

Comment: do you want this? http://plnkr.co/edit/zkF2f7opb9VAvc8uRcE7?p=preview

Comment: yes i have this, mentioned in question want to save percent value to my mysql database,

Comment: create an ajax request to the server. Take a look at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

The relation between jQuery and js is just like groovy and java, maybe the explaining is not exact. While if you've gotten the result by jQuery, you could use the result by js too, it's promiscuous. What you said that writing to database, you'd better to use ajax that can pass data from client (browser) to server. From your code, I get maybe you're using Angular.js. It's a framework that extends MVC, which has classified model view and controller...